# Offset raster Z value with second raster

Tags: qgis, raster, offset

I have 2 rasters in QGIS - one with holes and the other a full extent

Both rasters are the same CRS and extent, however the difference is their Z values due to being recorded differently.

Effectively, I would like to interpolate the raster with holes in it. I had thought that by offsetting the full extent rasters Z values to match those of the one with the holes in it and then patch the values in where data value is 0 may work.

[image: singlebeam]

[image: multibeam]

However, how can I offset a raster's Z values by another?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by offset?

Comment: @Kartograaf like lower the multibeam Z values to be more on the line of the Z values of the single-beam. Basically so that it gives a more realistic output instead of just the current multibeam z values punched in to the no data values of the single beam

Comment: I'm still having a hard time conceptualizing your problem, maybe a picture would help?

Comment: @Kartograaf I've attached images of the 2 rasters - hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for adding those. Are the differences in Z values consistent across the entire image? You might try some simple raster math and subtract one from the other then look at how much variation you see in the differences between their values (i.e. raster1 - raster2 = difference_Z)

Comment: @Kartograaf It can vary from ```-0.43``` to ```0.71``` across the 2 rasters z values. What I'd like the final (singlebeam) raster to look like is a 'continuation' of what the z values *would've* had the survey been done on the full area like the multibeam

Comment: That means sometimes the values are higher and sometimes they are lower, which is concerning. How do you know which of the two rasters is correct and which is incorrect in terms of elevation? Are you sure that they are accurately georeferenced with respect to one another?

Comment: @Kartograaf the singlebeam (one with the empty spaces) is the accurate one. I want to essentially interpolate it to cover the same area as the multibeam

Comment: What are the mean and standard deviation of the differences in elevation between the two rasters? Plot the distribution of those difference values as a histogram if possible.

Comment: @Kartograaf I tried plotting as a histogram, but it keeps crashing my QGIS. The ```Mean value: -0.03417321716141011``` and ```Standard deviation: 0.09507466593577414```

Comment: Ok so they are only 3.4cm different on average and the standard deviation is 9.5cm. What is the margin of error of the sensor used to aquire the data?

Comment: @Kartograaf that I'm not sure of as it was customer-supplied data from a 3rd party

Comment: Ok what is the horizontal resolution of your raster data?

Comment: @Kartograaf pixel width for single beam is ```0.28164484522285277``` in CRS ```EPSG:27700```

Comment: Alright so the pixels are 28x28 cm and the Z values only fluctuate by 3cm on average, with the most extreme fluctuations being around half a meter. In my opinion, these differences are likely to be a result of resampling error, differences in point density, instrument error, or noise in the data. In this case I'm not sure it makes sense to make inferences about the missing areas based on the other dataset unless you had some sort of systematic error across the whole scene (such as the vast majority of pixels falling in the same range, which would be evident as a large spike in the histogram).

Comment: it is a POC that the customer would like the single beam interpolated over the larger area

Comment: Something like this algorithm in QGIS may be the best you can do for them -> https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/fillnodata.html      The result will be much less resolute than the raster with complete coverage for obvious reasons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138747/discussion-between-guest-98732012-and-kartograaf).